# Can I make parent Variables accessible without a reference?

Tags: c#, multiple-inheritance

I have a list of classes in a class that inherits another class. I'd like to be able to access parent variables without having to use references (to make things more readable).

```
    public class MyCode : OtherCode
    {
        public string label;
        public MyCode()
        {
            label = "somestring";
            colour = 5;
            Console.WriteLine("colour is: " + colour); // this is ok
            List<particle> parts = new List<particle>();
            parts.Add( new particle() );
        }

        public class particle //I'd like this class to have access to the parent variables
        {
            public particle()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The colour is: " + colour); // can this be accessed without using a parent reference?
                //Console.WriteLine("The label is: " + label); // unaccessable
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }

    public class OtherCode
    {
        public int colour = 1;
        public OtherCode()
        {
            //I didn't do it
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to inherit parent variables this way so I can just type them 'as is' in the particles methods?

Apologies for the confusing example, I think I fluffed up by thinking I could use inheritance in this case..
What I'm wondering is it possible to have the nested class (particle) have access to label and colour without passing the reference to it on construction and using `Parent.variable` all over the place?

Comment: `particle` is not a `Coffee` and thus it shouldn't have a `flavor` or any concept of one, either make an interface or make the `cup` have a `flavor` (although I'm not sure a cup would be that tasty)

Comment: You're using inheritance wrong like @Sayse mentions (inheritance means "is-a", and coffee sure as hell isn'a cup) and your question is unclear. Explain what you would like to see happening, instead of "make more readable".

Comment: Sorry, but I think you have some things backwards. `Coffee : Cup` isn't a way of saying that there can't be coffee without a cup. Because there _can_ be coffee without a cup. The way you are declaring this it says that coffee is a specific kind of cup. Which it isn't. Cappucino is a Coffee and a Mug is a type of Cup which translates into `Cappucion : Coffee` and `Mug : Cup`.

So I think you should fix that and read up on OOP as a whole and then the answer to you question will come to you :)

Comment: I'm using a library, Cup actually represents that library I'm using.

Comment: Nested types don't inherit from their outer type. They can access private and protected members of the outer type, but they still need an instance of that type if they want to access non-static members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my rule to determine when to use inheritance.

Try to describe the problem and determine the verb in your sentence.

For example, what's the right sentence here?

- A cup **is** a coffee. **Really??**
- A cup **has** coffee. **I like it!** ([you need to use **composition** then](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition)).

Thus, you can't use inheritance because of laziness or whatever. Every concept has its use case and avoiding variable/property declarations isn't the goal of *inheritance*.

Comment: Makes sense, I was hoping to avoid having to pass in the parent and have Parent.var everywhere.

Comment: @Catnaps909 I believe you should create a new programming paradigm! OOP won't work as you like :P

Comment: haha, yeah I'm still learning. I just found it unreadable to have Parent. in front of everything as was wondering if there was a simpler way.

Comment: @Catnaps909 It's not unreadable. Today is unreadable for you, tomorrow it won't be unreadable anymore!